# .Net Framework 4.8 webapi site running on Windows Server 2022 takes several minutes to Recycle the application pool

Tags: asp.net, iis-10, windows-server-2022, dotnet-framework

I have a fully working .Net Framework 4.8 web site running on Windows Server 2019.  The site has both MVC and Api Controllers. Automatic or manual Recycling the site takes just a few seconds.

I ported this site to a Windows Server 2022 and now the Recycling time to end the previous process takes several minutes. The startup time on the new process is instant.

I  narrowed down the issue to it just being caused by accessing a webapi endpoint (ApiController).  If I only hit MVC pages, the recycling speed is normal.  I tested with having the endpoint just return a string (no database access) and this did not help.

I created a new .Net Framework MVC/API web site solution in Visual Studio 2022 from the template, and tested its behavior, and have the same problem. I did not make any changes to the template site. And only hitting the /api/values endpoint causes the recycle slow problem.

I have compared the IIS modules (optional windows features) installed between the 2019 and 2022 servers, and they are all the same.

Comment: 1. Since overlapped recycle is by default, the time to end the old process doesn't really matter. 2. If you do want to troubleshoot further though, then using a profiler or hang dump analysis is going to be required. If you are not familiar with such advanced skills, you will have to find someone else in your team or externally.

Comment: What's troubling is that especially with the the template site, there's nothing really to diagnose in a dump file. The endpoint returns fast as expected. Nothing is hanging.

Comment: Slowness to end a process doesn't always come from your own code. So saying "there's nothing really to diagnose" is far from true.

Comment: Not sure why the app pool needs to shut down, but I suspect the app is incompatible with overlapped instances. Seems there is a good chunk of housekeeping code missing from the global startup.

Comment: What's puzzling is why this wasn't a problem on server 2019.  And it's Microsoft's bare bones template site, so there's just so little to go wrong.